# snakemake: containerized vs container directives

Tags: snakemake

I am trying to figure out the differences between 'containerized:' and 'container:' directives in snakemake. From the documentation, it looks like 'containerized:' is to be used only with conda while 'container:' can be used with or without conda. Did I get it right ?